# How can I display output image with difference size of window?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to display an image on window using OpenCV function. However, anytime that I tried to display image will be fit to the size of display (as show in the example).

If I would like to display an image with difference size of window (for example. window size 1280x960px, and an image is 600x600px at offset coordinate 100x100px) How can I make them?

Sorry that I am beginner of OpenCV and Sorry for my poor English.

Thank you for help. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just make a bigger empty image and place the actual image in there using:

```
IplImage* smallerImage = cvLoadImage("image.jpg",1)
IplImage* biggerImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1280,960),8,3);

cvSetImageROI(biggerImage,cvRect(100,100,800,600);
cvResize(smallerImage,biggerImage);
cvResetImageROI(biggerImage);
cvShowImage("result",biggerImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cvNamedWindow(argument1, argument2)`
the 1th argument means "window name", and make the 2th argument to be `1`
(#define CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE 1) ,it means to fit the image size to the window size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I prefer to display image scaled are not fit to window size like that I show you in the example image.