# How can I Display output image with difference size of window? by using cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

According to [How can I display output image with difference size of window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102282/how-can-i-display-output-image-with-difference-size-of-window)

I would like to display an image on window using OpenCV function. However, anytime that I tried to display image will be fit to the size of display.

If I would like to display an image with difference size of window (for example. window size 1280x960px, and an image is 600x600px at offset coordinate 100x100px) How can I make them?

However, according to previous question I would like to use cv::Mat (C++ API) How cam I create them?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cv::Mat smallImage = cv::imread("myimage.jpg");
cv::Mat bigWindow = cv::Mat::zeros(960,1280, smallImage.type());

cv::Rect r(0,0,smallImage.cols, smallImage.rows);
cv::Mat roi = bigWindow(r);
smallImage.copyTo(roi);
cv::namedWindow("Display"); // cv::namedWindow("Display", 0); if you want to be able to  resize window
cv::imshow("Display", bigWindow);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

You had your answer in your previous question. Now if you want to get further with OpenCV, you have to read the [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/)!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @remi, however, I tried with your example but still not working, I also did same way as your code before then I  tried to google and ask in this site. Image still show only black screen, but if I shown "roi" (e.g. imshow("Display", roi)) image will appears.

Comment: Was it not compiling? Had forgotten type() info in function cv::Mat::zeros. Now this is a tested, compiling and working program that you can put in a main. If it does not work, add your full code to your question

Comment: make sure image that you read and "bigWindow" matrix have the same type, using smallImage.type() when creating the big window.

Comment: I got it! ... yes, because the type of matrix is different between them, and I changed it and worked! Thank you for your help, however I will read the Document before asking.